# Why do the same handle transfer Settings differ in both scenarios?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

Scene1 scene is set in the handle transfer function, switch to Scene2 scene and then set the same handle transfer function, why Scene1 can be used, Scene2 can not achieve it? Can you give me some doubts?
[The following picture is the VRTK script that I used to set the handle transfer capability:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKsbb.png)

Comment: You need to provide the code you are using. Handle transfer function? What is this one? Quite not clear what you are asking there.

Comment: Hello, the problem has changed, mainly in Unity3d in a scene to achieve the game object transfer function, through the HTC vive handle to send, but switch to another scene, the same settings can not achieve the ability, which is why?